# Why does my 12-month-old slap us?

Tags: toddler, behavior, violence

My 12-month-old son has just recently taken to slapping us - the parents. He has been directing the slaps to our faces, chests and arms.

What is causing this? Is there anyway for us to stop it?

Answer (score 2):

Babies love attention and if he gets a funny reaction (e.g. you saying "No no no!") it can be plenty of fun (from their perspective).

I'm a father of 3 and my kids as young babies have gone through various phases of pulling hair, or slapping the face, or biting.

None of it was malicious (it was all playful), so I figured it was pretty normal.

To abate this sort of thing I tried to firstly not react when they did it (make it less of a game), and secondly tried to distract them into a different game (e.g. clapping hands, singing, putting hands up in the air) in preference to scolding them.